# Electrical Charisteristics of PIC24FJ1024GB610

Tags: current, pic, electrical

I am reading the Electrical characteristics of PIC24FJ1024GB610 from it's Datasheet http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30010074e.pdf 
(Page 419/468).

it mentions:

> Maximum output current sunk by any I/O pin    25 mA
>
> Maximum output current sourced by any I/O pin   25 mA
>
> Maximum current sunk by all ports     200 mA
>
> Maximum current sourced by all ports  200 mA

Does it mean that the maximum operational current sourced/sunk to/by the PIC24 is 25 mA, and the max current allowed to/from the I/O pins is 200mA

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the maximum that can be sunk / sourced by any one pin is 25mA and that the maximum that the chip can sink / source simultaneously across all pins is 200mA.

Comment: So if we are using 100 pins or 10 pins, the max our chip can source / sink simultaneously is 200 mA , did I get that right?

Comment: Yes - for example you can have up to 8 pins simultaneously sinking the max 25mA each, or 16 pins sinking 12.5mA each